# Why does $\frac{dy}{dx} \propto y$ imply $x_1 - x_2$ is constant for $\frac{y_2}{y_1}$ constant where $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ can vary?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, physics

The time taken for the activity of a radioactive sample to halve is called the half-life. This is a constant.

More generally, given the curve $y=Ae^{-bx}$, given $y_1$ and $y_2 = ky_1$, then $\frac{y_2}{y_1}$ is always the same number for all choices of $y_1$.

I can justify this by writing $y_1 = Ae^{-bx_1}$ and $y_2 = Ae^{-bx_2}$ and then using $y_2 = ky_1$ to get $x_1 - x_2 = \frac{1}{b} \ln k$, which is a constant.

But is there anyway to justify this starting from the fact that we have a curve that satisfies $\frac{dy}{dx} \propto y$?

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{dy}{dx} \propto y \Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx} = ky \ $   ($k$ is a constant)

Now you're provided with 2 arbitrary points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$.

So,

$\begin{align}&\int_{y_1}^{y_2}\frac{dy}{y} = k\int_{x_1}^{x_2} dx \\\Rightarrow \ & \ln\frac{y_2}{y_1} = k(x_2- x_1) \text{ or }  \boxed{x_1 - x_2 = \frac1k\ln\frac{y_1}{y_2}}\end{align}$

Now, $k$ and  $\frac{y_1}{y_2}$ are constats. So, $\boxed{x_1- x_2}$ is also constant

Comment: Thank you, but this is very similar to my approach. I was wondering more if this fact should be obvious given that the rate of change is proportional to the number of atoms present (in this context)? An explanation using the gradient more directly?

Comment: The derivative or gradient being proportional to the function implies that the function is of the form $y = Ae^{-bx}$(decaying as you've used). So, by any way it will result in the form $\frac{y_1}{y_2} = Ae^{-(x_1 - x_2)} = $ constant, implying $x_1 - x_2$ is constant.